# Getting the value of an image field in Plone 3.x with FSS

Tags: json, migration, plone, plone-3.x, file-system-storage

I'm trying to migrate an old Plone 3.3 site that uses 
[FileSystemStorage](https://plone.org/products/filesystemstorage) using [Mikko's Simple JSON export script](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/04/exporting-plone-content-as-json/).

Everything runs fine, except for the absence of a value on the image fields, which are returned as empty strings (`''`):

```
[
    ...
    {
        "allowDiscussion": false, 
        "contributors": [], 
        "creation_date": "2009-11-04T15:15:36-02:00", 
        "creators": [
            "johndoe"
        ], 
        "description": "", 
        "effectiveDate": null, 
        "excludeFromNav": false, 
        "expirationDate": null, 
        "id": "banner_vertical.jpg", 
        "image": "", 
        "language": "", 
        "location": "", 
        "modification_date": "2009-11-04T15:15:37-02:00", 
        "portal_type": "Image", 
        "relatedItems": [], 
        "rights": "", 
        "subject": [], 
        "title": "Banner vertical", 
        "urlLegend": "http://"
    },
    ...
 ]
```

Any hint?

([iw.fss](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iw.fss/2.8.0rc5) version used is 2.8.0rc5).

Comment: Two random notes by my side (too much time is passed from my last experience on FSS... and I don't miss it).
1. what I remember is that APIs were working differently, like you were forced to call something like `obj.getFile().read()` (or `getImage` in your case probably) to get the stream; maybe Mikko's script is not supporting FSS.
2. Also, check if your FSS is really using the storage for images.
Good luck!

Comment: I can confirm @keul's note. the API to interact with FSS based fields is different. You may need implement a `if` in mikkos script :-)

Comment: I can confirm. I don't know what's FSS. At least anymore.

Answer (score 1):

FSS was not known or used by the site for which the script has been made.

You might want to retrofit `convert()` and other methods to support your use case.